# Can android support a deeplink with an immediate '?' after the host URL?

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

Our URL currently has this schema:

> https://www.example.com/?dialog=login

I have tried this:

```
<data android:host="www.example.com" />
<data android:host="example.com" />
<data android:pathPrefix="?dialog" />
<data android:scheme="https" />
<data android:scheme="http" />
```

But it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: try with pathPattern. <data android:pathPattern="dialog.*" />

Comment: @xingjiu Sadly, it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<intent-filter>
...
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" 
android:pathPrefix="?dialog=login" />
</intent-filter>
```

**EDIT:**

I did not pay attention to the format of the path. Your URL: ***https://www.example.com/?dialog=login*** , the query string [**?dialog=login**]  is not part of the path so **you cannot filter** on query strings.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answers are not appreciated .

Comment: Beginning with '?' gives an error: 'pathPrefix should start with / '

Comment: Don't specify any `android:pathPrefix` (or only set it to `/`). The character `?` is part of the query, not the path.